# Prevent AddOn domain from redirecting to subdomain (Bluehost)

Tags: subdomain, bluehost

Hi my AddOn domain keeps on redirecting to a subdomain.
I also noticed that this also happens when I try accessing the folder where I pointed the AddOn domain

```
AddOn Domain: addon.com
Subdomain: addon.maindomain.com
Subfolder: maindomain.com/addon
```

Why is this so? I've seen from the Domain Manager a message like this though.

Addon Parent: The domain addon.com is aliased to addon.maindomain.com

How can I prevent the redirection from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of these:

file: maindomain/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

or

file: maindomain/addon/.htaccess

```
writeEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon.maindomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.addon.maindomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addon.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Cheers!

Ref:

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/498

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/134